# Using LINQ extension method syntax on a MatchCollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
MatchCollection matches = myRegEx.Matches(content);

bool result = (from Match m in matches
               where m.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128
               select m).Any();
```

Is there a way to do this using the LINQ extension method syntax?

Something like this:

```
bool result = matches.Any(x => ... );
```

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

matches.Cast<Match>().Any(x => x.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128)
```

You just need to convert it from an `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<Match>` (IEnumerable<T>) to get access to the LINQ extension provided on IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: This works, just make sure you are `using System.Linq` else it will give a syntax error

Comment: Thank you, to anyone confused, `Cast` is not needed since C# 8.0, but the code won't compile in earlier language versions if it is not provided.

Comment: I found if i upgraded the project to NetStandard2.1 match.Any() worked.

Answer (score 48):

When you specify an *explicit* range variable type, the compiler inserts a call to `Cast<T>`. So this:

```
bool result = (from Match m in matches
               where m.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128
               select m).Any();
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
bool result = matches.Cast<Match>()
                     .Where(m => m.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128)
                     .Any();
```

which can also be written as:

```
bool result = matches.Cast<Match>()
                     .Any(m => m.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128);
```

In this case the `Cast` call is required because [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) only implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. Almost all the LINQ to Objects extension methods are targeted at `IEnumerable<T>`, with the notable exceptions of `Cast` and `OfType`, both of which are used to convert a "weakly" typed collection (such as `MatchCollection`) into a generic `IEnumerable<T>` - which then allows for further LINQ operations.

Comment: On MSDN: [Enumerable.Cast<TResult> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
var matches = myRegEx.Matches(content).Cast<Match>();
```

For reference, please see [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

> Converts the elements of an `IEnumerable` to the specified type.

Basically it's one way of turning an `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be something like this:

```
bool result = matches.Cast<Match>().Any(m => m.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128);
```

Comment: No. The whole point is that `MatchCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`. It is not strongly-typed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
List<Match> matchList = matches.Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable enumerable)
 {
      foreach(object item in enumerable)
          yield return (T)item;
 }
```

Then you should be able to call this extension method to turn it into an IEnumerable:

```
 matches.AsEnumerable<Match>().Any(x => x.Groups["name"].Value.Length > 128);
```

Comment: This is better than mine, I didn't remember that Any took a predicate.

Comment: No. The whole point is that `MatchCollection` only implements `IEnumerable`. It is not strongly-typed.

Comment: @Jason except that it is Castable to an IEnumberable<T> via IEnumberable.Cast<T>

Comment: @msarchet: Yes, I know, which is why I upvoted your answer. This answer, before the edit, wouldn't have even compiled.