# Using Linq with Regex to remove empty matches

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I need to remove zero-length matches from a match collection in c# regex

My attempt:

```
MatchCollection Matches = _RVar.Matches(arg);
List<Match> ValidMatches = Matches.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Where(J => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(J.Value))
                                  .ToList<Match>();
```

Visual Studio says:

> Error 1   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method
>   'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But on this codeproject [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/751437/Using-Linq-with-Regular-Expression-results), AsEnumerable is a method of Regex.MatchCollection.

Anyone know why I get the error?

Comment: See following webpage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274422/using-linq-extension-method-syntax-on-matchcollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample you linked to defines a custom `AsEnumerable` extension method on `MatchCollection`.

```
public static IEnumerable<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match> AsEnumerable(this System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection mc)
{
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in mc)
    {
        yield return m;
    }
}
```

You can either do that, or use `Cast` extension method:

```
List<Match> ValidMatches
    = Matches.Cast<Match>().Where(J => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(J.Value)).
```

`Cast` is useful when you need to transform a collection that implements non-generic `IEnumerable` into a generic `IEnumerable<T>`, which is exactly the case here.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your explanation