# How to get specific text from string in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract the profile name from their type name. For example, the input type name are as following:

"ST230X52"; "S310X74"; "WT305X62.5"; "305x457x127UBT"

So how can I get the output as:
"ST"; "S" ; "WT"; "UBT"

Comment: Hi, is there a list of filters or is it just ST, S, WT, and UBT? And also, will the profile name always be at the front and at the end?

Comment: Hi @Tommy. There is no list. These are profile name of structure framing so they usually the "ST,S,WT,UBT..." are the short name of the profile. and following is the size of the profile for example: 230X52.

Comment: Ok, but are the profile names always at the two ends of the strings?

Comment: Is it always either `{letters}{number}X{number}` or `{number}x{number}x{number}{letters}`? Or at there other variants?

Comment: Hi Tommy & Enigmativity: The profile name is always as 4 cases: {letters}{number}X{number} ; {letters}{number}X{number}X{number} ; {number}x{number}{letters}; {number}x{number}x{number}{letters}. The "X" letter can be lower or capital.

Comment: @NinhTruongHuuHa - Please use the `@` notification when responding. You can only `@` one person at a time so it is best to answer each person individually.

Comment: @NinhTruongHuuHa - The info you put in the comment should be included in your question. Can you please add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best thing to do this is with Reguler Expressions, use code below:

**Note:** I do this like what is example was: Character casing, first and end

```cs
public static string GetProfileName(string input)
{
    List<char> result = new List<char>();
    bool startFinding = false;

    foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
    {
        // Is match A to Z in upper case?
        if (Regex.IsMatch(c.ToString(), "[A-Z]"))
        {
            result.Add(c);
            startFinding = true;
        }
        else if(startFinding)
        {
            // End looping
            break;
        }
    }

    return new string(result.ToArray());
}
```

#### Explain this method

**Variables:**

At first, I define `List<char>` as variable, Becuase it will be the result.

And `startFinding` defines did method start finding characters from A-Z or not.

**Method:**

I made loop in every character (`foreach`)

If character was from `A-Z` in uppercase (using `Regex`):

> Add this character to `result`

> Change `startFinding` to `true`

Else if `startFinding` was `true`

> End this loop (`break`)

---

#### Results:

```
ST
S
WT
UBT
```

Comment: @Tommy , I made this example like the examples that he gives, in his examples was no `X` with any character it was `ST...X`, And my method will stop recoring to `result` if the `A-Z` ends :)

Comment: Thanks @Muaath for your sample and great explanation. I have tried it and it work perfectly to get the profile short name.

Comment: @Tommy: For the steel structure profile, there is not profile with x letter. I think because they don't want to be confused with the x letter of the size.

Comment: @NinhTruongHuuHa - This answer doesn't work for `"305X457X127UBT"` which, according to your comment in the question, is a valid input. Please make sure you clearly specify your questions and validate the answers you choose.

Comment: @Enigmativity: it did work for "305X457X127UBT" case as well. I have implemented the code successfully :).

Comment: @NinhTruongHuuHa - When I run `GetProfileName("305X457X127UBT")` the result I get is `"X"` and not `"UBT"`. Did you modify the code from this answer?

Comment: @Enigmativity This is because you make X in uppercase, I made this method to be similar 100% to the question examples, the example has x Not X, Try with lowercase and it will work :)

Comment: @Muaath - The OP has said this in the comments: "The profile name is always as 4 cases: {letters}{number}X{number} ; {letters}{number}X{number}X{number} ; {number}x{number}{letters}; {number}x{number}x{number}{letters}. The "X" letter can be lower or capital."

Comment: @Enigmativity - But in last example it has x in lower, Not in upper :)

Comment: @Muaath - Yes, but the OP has said that it can be either upper or lower case.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this:

```
public static string Extract(string text) =>
    Regex.Matches(text, @"[^\d.]+").Cast<Match>()
         .FirstOrDefault(match => match.Value.ToLower() != "x")?.Value;
```

First, I find matches of a run of characters that contains no digits or decimals.  Then I return the first such run that is not just an "x" (case insensitive).  Returns `null` if no match exists.

Comment: @CoolBots, You've edited my answer but without `.Cast<Match>` it produces `error CS1061: 'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I tested it - what framework are you using? `MatchCollection` is an `IEnumerable<Match>`. Sorry, didn't mean to break it, notice I have the same in my answer as well - I wonder if there's a difference between .Net Core and .NET Framework on the implemented interfaces? I'll check.

Comment: In versions prior to C# 8.0, `.Cast<Match>` is required.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7274451/1563833 for more info.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize that. In C# 8 it's entirely redundant. I restored it in your code, and I'll edit my answer to reflect that as well. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: It's acutally not the language version, it's specifically .NET Framework vs .NET Core (just tested .NET Core 3.1 with C# 7 - no need for `Cast<Match>()` call). In .NET Framework, `MatchCollection` is `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 0):

While this question doesn't suffer from a lack of answers, I thought I'd add one more :)

The question describes a great use case for *domain-specific type* - the `string` containing the *product type* is *really not a string at all in context of OP's domain*. Consider the following class (RegEx matching shamelessly stolen from @Wyck's answer):

#### Domain-Specific Type

```cs
class ProductType
{
    private static Regex profileNameRule = new Regex(@"[^\d.]+");

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; private set; }

    private string ExtractProfileName(string text)
        => profileNameRule.Matches(text)
                          .Cast<Match>()   // this call is necessary on .NET Framework, but not on .NET Core
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToLower() != "x")?.Value;

    private ProductType(string name)
        => (Name, ProfileName) = (name, ExtractProfileName(name));

    public static implicit operator ProductType(string name)
        => new ProductType(name);
}
```

#### Explanation:

The class has a private constructor, so the only way to create an instance of it is using the *implicit conversion* from `string` - while implicit conversions can be bad in cases where a failure is possible, in this case, the conversion always succeeds (you might get an invalid product type - if the entered string represented an invalid product type to begin with, but it won't fail).

The `Regex` object that defines the rule which represents a *profile name* is `static`, to avoid unnecessary allocations;  the *profile name* is calculated once, during construction of the object.

#### Usage example:

```cs
var products = new ProductType[] { "ST230X52", "S310X74", "WT305X62.5", "305x457x127UBT" };

foreach (var product in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Product name: {product.Name}, Profile name: {product.ProfileName}");
}

/*
    OUTPUT:

Product name: ST230X52, Profile name: ST
Product name: S310X74, Profile name: S
Product name: WT305X62.5, Profile name: WT
Product name: 305x457x127UBT, Profile name: UBT
           
*/
```

#### Why use this approach

The idea of introducing *domain-specific types* in your code can greatly improve readability, as the logic related to inner-workings of such types is now encapsulated within the type itself. Such types can also be *unit tested*, to ensure proper functionality. The types can also be grouped into a library that can be shared, for instance, across various tiers of an *n-tier application*, or various services of a *microservices architecture application*, etc.

#### Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

does this small routine solve your problem?

```
var str = "ST230X52"
let noncode = Set<Character>(arrayLiteral: "0","1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "X", "x")
var profileName = ""
    if !noncode.contains(letter) {
        profileName += String(letter)
    }
}
print(profileName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample but I am sorry that I am quite new to c# so when I copy your code to Visual studio, it show error of the format. So could you please help me with the full structure code?