# Find 2 letter or 3 letters from wordlist

Tags: c#

I have a 256 wordlist with 8 digits like "DDUUDDUU", "DDDDUUUU", "DDUUUUUU" and I am having a hard time trying to match any combination of 2 or 3 consecutive letters like "UUDDUUUU", "DDDUUDDD"

```
            foreach (var eachWord in AAAA.Values) {

            int iCountU = 0;
            int iCountD = 0;
            char iLastChar = (char)106;

            foreach (char letter in eachWord) {
                if (letter == 'D') {
                    if (iCountD < 3) {
                        if (letter != iLastChar) {
                            iLastChar = letter;
                            iCountD = 1;
                        } else {
                            iCountD += 1;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (letter == 'U') {
                    if (iCountU < 3) {
                        if (letter != iLastChar) {
                            iLastChar = letter;
                            iCountU = 1;
                        } else {
                            iCountU += 1;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            if (iCountU > 2 && iCountD > 2) {
                BBBB[eachWord] = eachWord;
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you mean find the strings containing 2 or 3 consecutive same letters, but not 4 or more, and not single?

Comment: correct not 4 or more and not single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this implementation counts the maximum consecutive occurrences for each character, the second word evaluates as `{2,4}` which overrides `{2,3}` and doesn't count as a match.

```
int matches = 0;
var wordList = new string[] { "DDUUUDUD", "DDUUUUDU" };
foreach (string word in wordList)
{
    char? previous = null;
    int count = 0;
    var results = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char letter in word)
    {
        if (letter == previous)
            results[letter] = Math.Max(results.ContainsKey(letter) ? results[letter] : 0, ++count);
        else
            count = 1;
        previous = letter;
    }
    if (results.Values.SequenceEqual(new int[] {2,3}) || results.Values.SequenceEqual(new int[] {3,2}))
        matches++;
}
Console.WriteLine(matches);
```

Comment: the results are like 200 when in fact it should be like 50.. DDUUUDUD count but DDUUUUUU doesn't because it has to have (2 then 3) or (3 then 2) or (2 then 2) or (3 then 3) but not (2 then 4) or not (3 then 4).. hope this makes sense

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you want to change the way matches are counted, just edit the final sequence count.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C# compiler with me, here is a python code (with many element pretending in C# style)

```
AAAA=["DDUUDDUU", "DDDDUUUU"]
for word in AAAA:
    isFirst=True
    maxCon=0
    currCon=1
    for c in word:
        if isFirst:
            isFirst=False
        else:
            if c==prev:
                currCon+=1
                maxCon=max(maxCon,currCon)
            else:
                currCon=1
        prev=c
    if maxCon in (2,3):
        print(word,maxCon)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is surprisingly simple with a Regular Expression:

```
static bool testString(string test)
{
    return Regex.Matches(test, @"([a-zA-Z])\1+").Any(x => x.Length == 2 || x.Length == 3);
}
```

The main trick is that the `\1+` will create a group when it encounters a new character and add the next characters that match the first character to that match group.

Note on older .NET versions you may need to use `Cast<Match>`, as `Regex.Matches(test, @"([a-zA-Z])\1+").Cast<Match>().Any(x => x.Length == 2 || x.Length == 3)`

Comment: This worked fine, but there's no `Any()` in `MatchCollection` at least in MS Framework 4.7.2, you need to `.Cast<Match>()` before calling that method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274422/using-linq-extension-method-syntax-on-a-matchcollection).

Comment: @DanielManta It looks like it may have been added in .NET 5, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=net-5.0) has `Any` in the list of extension methods.

Comment: the results are like 200 when in fact it should be like 50.. DDUUUDUD count but DDUUUUUU doesn't because it has to have (2 then 3) or (3 then 2) or (2 then 2) or (3 then 3) but not (2 then 4) or not (3 then 4).. hope this makes sense

Comment: @XK8ER If it can only have groups of 2 or 3 and fails if it has groups of any other length, you could just change `Any` to `All`.